# What would be the regex?

Tags: java, regex

Let say I have string like this :

```
default-src http:// adobe.com:234 http:// omntsd.org:8790 ; frame-ancestors 'self' http:// dhimana.com:8690 http:// nishkala.com:8080  ; script-src http:// google.com:80 http:// jquery.com:80
frame-ancestors 'self' http:// dhimana.com:8690 http:// nishkala.com:8080  ; script-src http:// google.com:80 http:// jquery.com:80
default-src http:// adobe.com:234 http:// omntsd.org:8790 ; frame-ancestors 'self' http:// dhimana.com:8690 http:// nishkala.com:8080 
default-src http:// adobe.com:234 http:// omntsd.org:8790 ; frame-ancestors 'self' http:// dhimana.com:8690 http:// nishkala.com:8080  ;
```

Now, what would be the regular expression(in Java) to match the pattern frame-ancestors part with the semi colon (`;`) in beginning.

Means I want to match :

`"; frame-ancestors 'self' http:// dhimana.com:8690 http:// nishkala.com:8080  "` for first,third and fourth string AND `"frame-ancestors 'self' http:// dhimana.com:8690 http:// nishkala.com:8080  "` for the second string.

Using `;[ ]*frame-ancestors[^;]*` regex I can match for first,third and fourth. But not the second one.

Comment: using   ;[ ]*frame-ancestors[^;]*  regex I can match for first,third and fourth. But not the second one.

Comment: [`;?[ ]*frame-ancestors[^;]*`](https://regex101.com/r/rF1pZ0/1)? Make the first `;` optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first `;` optional.

Use

```
;?[ ]*frame-ancestors[^;]*
 ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF1pZ0/1)